# Can't import MediaPlayer from External Libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

Ok I read too many Threads from many people who somewhat have a similar problem but none of them solved my problem so please assist me with my huge "pain in the ass"-problem which I seem to not fully understand.

I'm trying to use the MediaPlayer Class from javafx.scene.media and sadly the media class isn't inherited in the default SDK's since Java 9 I think and I'm using Java Version 12. So naturally I have to add the jafafx.scene.media library (jar-Format) manually which should be the easiest step in the world.

I am able to add it via "Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add Library" and it shows up in my external library menu but none of my classes can import it.
That's my first Java project (I come from C#) and I even asked my proffessor but he didn't have a clue either. I even tried to create a new project and add it but with no success.

(I tried adding the library via Maven-Dependency, too, with no success)

Then I thought that another library could work and I added vlcj (VLC-Player) and at least it does find something to import after going to "Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies" and changing the vlcj library from compile to Provided.
But now when importing I get the following error: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XphQC.png)

I am *so* confused. And it's even for a school project.
Please give me advice if you have any or tell me if I need to drop more infos.

Much Love

Kong

Comment: Adding a library is not enough, the library must be also in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies). Also, if you are using Java 9+ module system, you have to adjust your `module-info.java` file for that. Or just delete this file and don't use Java modules for this project for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Please post this as an answer so I can upvote it.
You made a young programmer very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a library is not enough, the library must be also in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

Also, if you are using Java 9+ module system, you have to adjust your `module-info.java` file for that. Or just delete this file and don't use Java modules for this project for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: No cape required for you to be a hero.
PS: That solution worked for the "declared but module x does not read it" error. Still don't know how to solve the scene.media library but I don't need it anymore.